# Get array of files from directory as impersonated user

Tags: c#, directory, impersonation

How to get the files which are visible for the impersonated user ? The code below gives me all the files, even if the impersonated user shouldn't be able to read them.

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = Identity.Impersonate())
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder");
}
```

The variable Identity is a [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx).

Comment: It is not completely clear to me what does it mean "_files which are visible_": do you mean something like "_files which are accessible_"? If that is the case, try to take a look to [Directory.GetAccessControl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f66bc2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)